# S3 Lifecycle error on AWS EMR reading AWS Redshift using PySpark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am trying to read redshift table into EMR cluster using pyspark. I am currently running my code on shell using pyspark but eventually want to make a script that I can submit using `spark-submit`. I am using 4 jar files to make pyspark be able to connect and read data from redshift.

I start pyspark using:

`pyspark --jars minimal-json-0.9.5.jar,RedshiftJDBC4-no-awssdk-1.2.41.1065.jar,spark-avro_2.11-3.0.0.jar,spark-redshift_2.10-2.0.1.jar`

Then I am running below code:

```
key = "<key>"
secret = "<secret>"

redshift_url = "jdbc:redshift://<cluster>:<port>/<dbname>?user=<username>&password=<password>"
redshift_query = "select * from test"
redshift_temp_s3 = "s3a://{}:{}@<bucket-name>/".format(key, secret)

data = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
       .option("url", redshift_url)
       .option("query", redshift_query)
       .option("tempdir", redshift_temp_s3)
       .option("forward_spark_s3_credentials", "true")
       .load()
```

Error Stacktrace:

```
WARN Utils$: An error occurred while trying to read the S3 bucket lifecycle configuration
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified bucket is not valid. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidBucketName; Request ID: FS6MDX8P2MBG5T0G; S3 Extended Request ID: qH1q9y1C2EWIozr3WH2Qt7ujoBCpwLuJW6W77afE2SKrDiLOnKvhGvPC8mSWxDKmR6Dx0AlyoB4=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: qH1q9y1C2EWIozr3WH2Qt7ujoBCpwLuJW6W77afE2SKrDiLOnKvhGvPC8mSWxDKmR6Dx0AlyoB4=
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1828)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1412)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1374)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
```

Then it waits a couple of seconds before showing the correct output. I also see the folder created in the s3 bucket. I have not turned on bucket versioning but it does have a lifecycle created. I do not understand why it first shows the error and then the correct output as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how did you resolved this? I am seeing the same issue, first WARN and then output.